# AngularJS / Ionic Header Not Binding Correctly When First Viewed

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, ionic-view

I have a simple Angular/Ionic View that I am binding a model to. Below is an example of the controller:

```
.controller('LocationDetailsCtrl',function($scope,$http,$stateParams,$local    storage,$log,Locations){

   var locationId = $stateParams.locationId;

   Locations.setCurrent(locationId);

   var model = {
       location:null
   };

   Locations.getById(locationId)
     .then(function(location){
       $scope.model.location = location;
     },function(error){
       $log.error(error);
   });

   $scope.model = model;
}
```

I am being the property `$scope.model.location.name` to the header title on the view.

This looks like the following

```
<ion-view view-title="{{model.location.name}}">
   <ion-content>

   ... other model binding stuff here works fine

   </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

The problem I am running into is that when the view loads the first time, everything loads fine except the header binding. Then I can go to another view, and come back to this iew and the title is bound correctly the model on my scope.

Here are screenshots

First time the view loads..

[image]

After I navigate to another view and come back

[image]

Not sure why it wouldn't bind the first time when all the other `$scope.model.location.XXXX` properties bind correctly and update in the view.

Comment: On which element , you have define ng-controller ?

Comment: Anyway can you replicate this in a simplified codepen?

Answer (score 0):

Use

> if (!$scope.$$phase) $scope.$apply()

after you after

> $scope.model.location = location;